# Keyboard shorcut to select whole line, starting at end of the line?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I know how to select a line from the beginning to the end, starting from the beginning of the line - `shift+end`

How do I do the same thing, but beginning from end of line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the whole line starting from the end, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>.